# numpy double installation (pip vs apt-get)

Tags: numpy, pip, apt-get

I am using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have tensorflow, scipy, numpy installed, but when I try installing sklearn or opencv using apt-get, another numpy is installed whose version is 1.8 and it "overwrites" the one I previously installed using pip which is 1.12. I tried updating it then, because I need 1.12, but it does not work.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, is it because apt-get has priority over pip?

How do I force update numpy, or just remove the one installed through apt-get without removing the whole package which installed it as a dependency (e.g. sklearn)?

Comment: It might be worth finding out about virtualemnv to deal with this kind of thing

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar problem in Debian. This is how I solved (workaround) this.

numpy versions:

- apt-get: v1.8, at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, let this be **"path1"**
- pip: v1.12, at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`,let this be **"path2"**

Add **BOTH path1 and path2** to the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, and **make path2 before path1**, if you want the pip version as default.

Thus, in the shell config, say *~/.bashrc*, add this line (replace path1/2 with the real path):

```
export PYTHONPATH=path2:path1:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Then restart the shell.

You can test if it works with this command: `$ python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__file__"`, and make sure the path is path2.

---

I tried skipping path1, i.e. `export PYTHONPATH=path2:${PYTHONPATH}`, but this didn't work.

Comment: What does "but this didn't work" on the last line actually mean? You had some essential package on path1, and you needed both path1 and path2 to be visible to python?

Comment: I need the one in path2, but python still always imports that from path1, if I don't explicitly add path1 after path2 in the PYTHONPATH.